# SWIG C++ -> Java - typemapping own string class just like std::string

Tags: java, string, swig

I'm struggling to adapt the SWIG built-in `std_string.i` to work for my own string class.

What I did:

- Assuming my own string class is called my::space::String
- Copy-pasted `std_string.i` into my own `.i` file and replaced

  - `namespace std {` by `namespace my { namespace space {`
  - Lowercase `string` by `String`
  - `#include <string>` by `#include <myownheader.h>`

The problem is that I'm getting a syntax error that I don't understand and which is not helpful:

```
wrapmystring.i:90: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

It's this line in the `const String &` typemap part:

```
%typemap(directorout,warning=SWIGWARN_TYPEMAP_THREAD_UNSAFE_MSG) const String &
%{ if(!$input) {
     SWIG_JavaThrowException(jenv, SWIG_JavaNullPointerException, "null string");
     return $null;
   }
   const char *$1_pstr = (const char *)jenv->GetStringUTFChars($input, 0);
   if (!$1_pstr) return $null;
   /* possible thread/reentrant code problem */
   static $*1_ltype $1_str;
   $1_str = $1_pstr; <=================== syntax error points here
   $result = &$1_str;
   jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars($input, $1_pstr); %}
```

Any idea why it works in `std_string.i` and not with my own class?